# SerializedName в android

Tags: android

Столкнулся с проблемой  вот такой ответ от сервера, нужно получить список "features"

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("547c485078e91ff65fe68b2f"), 
"contractNumber" : "", 
"coordinates" : {
    "lat" : 55.71418, 
    "lon" : 37.573763
}, 
"country" : "Россия", 
…
"phone" : "375296416456", 
"review" : true, 
"features" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("556c2ca4eb21580300498efb")
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("556c80f93ebd7c030029a72f")
    }
]
```

}

пробовал так, но features всегда == null

```
@SerializedName("features")
public List<Features> features;

public class Features {
    @SerializedName("_id")
    public String objectId;
}
```

Comment: Вся проблема в ObjectId. Посмотрите вое [этот](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23061611/converting-bson-type-objectid-to-json-storing-in-mongodb-java) пост.

Comment: Не совсем понял, если не сложно объясните на примере. Спасибо.

Comment: Проблема в том, что ваши данные не в JSON формате. Это какой-то другой формат. Согласно правилам JSON, поле не может иметь значение ObjectId("556c80f93ebd7c030029a72f")

Comment: @SerializedName("features")
    public List<Features> feature;


    public class Features{
        @SerializedName("_id")
        public String id;
    }    Это отлично работает при условии что сервер отдает "features" проблема была на сервере